# Losing return button after changing navigation type to horizontal

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I'm changing view with:

```
interfaceController.pushController(withName: "CarInfoController", context: context)
```

in my `VisitHistoryCellController`.

When I go to `CarInfoController`, there is a default return button to go back. After that I have a few buttons that use:

```
let controllerNames = ["CarInfoController", "ServiceDetailInfoController"]
let contexts = [AnyObject]()

WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: controllerNames, contexts: contexts, orientation: .horizontal, pageIndex: 1)
```

to go to the next page. When I swipe left to return to the previous page, the return button is gone. I think it's because I changed style of my `WKInterfaceController` type `CarInfoController` with the code above. Question: how can I make return button to go back after the `swipe` back to `CarInfoController` page?

Comment: When you use `pushController` you're pushing another view on the stack, by default this give you a back button. Whether you press the back button or swipe left you're triggering the same response. If the VC you're on is the root of a flow, the back button will be removed, because their is nothing to go back too.